# Debug the create! method inside the controller create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

The rails 3 appis is using the create! method inside the create of a controller.

Sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not.It fails consistently with always the same use case, however i have checked and rechecked and cannot understand why it fails.

The create! method fails silently, there is no indication on the logs of the problem. How can I make the create! methode more verbose?

Code :

```
class NotificationPaiementsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except =>[:create]
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:create]

  def create
    logger.debug "params is #{params}"
    logger.debug "invoice is #{params[:invoice]}"
    logger.debug "payment_status is #{params[:payment_status]}"

    logger.debug "txn_id is #{params[:txn_id]}"

    @notification_paiement = NotificationPaiement.create!(:params => params,
                                              :cart_id => params[:invoice],
                                              :status=> params[:payment_status],
                                              :transaction_id => params[:txn_id])

    logger.debug "notification_paiement is #{@notification_paiement}"
    render :nothing=>true
  end
end
```

EDIT:
Thx for your answers, it would have been faster to catch exception, but i managed to identify the problem using new and savevia the console. At the save i had an error about UTF-8 encoding : ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.
 Paypal was changing "molière" in "moli\xE8re" and the error was never displayed.

Comment: Can you paste your `NotificationPaiement` model and an example call to `NotificationPaiementsController#create`, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`create!` constructor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21) raises an exception if it fails:

> Creates an object just like `Base.create` but calls `save!` instead of `save` so an exception is raised if the record is invalid.

So, if you're going to use `create!`, you should wrap it in exception handling:

```
begin
  @notification_paiement = NotificationPaiement.create!(...
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  # Deal with your errors.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily remove the backtrace silencers in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb in case exception info is being swallowed.